# Dictionary of lists from list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of lists of data:

```
[[1422029700000, 230.84, 230.42, 230.31, 230.32, 378], [1422029800000, 231.84, 231.42, 231.31, 231.32, 379], ...]
```

and a list of keys:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

I want to combine them to a dictionary of lists so it looks like:

```
['a': [1422029700000, 1422029800000], 'b': [230.84, 231.84], ...]
```

I can do this using loops but I am looking for a pythonic way.

Answer (score 6):

It is quite simple:

```
In [1]: keys = ['a','b','c']

In [2]: values = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

In [7]: dict(zip(keys, zip(*values)))
Out[7]: {'a': (1, 4, 7), 'b': (2, 5, 8), 'c': (3, 6, 9)}
```

If you need lists as values:

```
In [8]: dict(zip(keys, [list(t) for t in zip(*values)]))
Out[8]: {'a': [1, 4, 7], 'b': [2, 5, 8], 'c': [3, 6, 9]}
```

or:

```
In [9]: dict(zip(keys, map(list, zip(*values))))
Out[9]: {'a': [1, 4, 7], 'b': [2, 5, 8], 'c': [3, 6, 9]}
```

Comment: Here you go, lists as values.

Comment: Tested it out, and works just fine for my purposes. Much faster and easier to access data than loops and arrays and such. I appreciate the quick answer

Comment: You are welcome! Please, next time prepare the example inputs and outputs in such a way that they are ready to be copied and pasted into editor/interactive session, this will save us a bit of time and, more importantly, will make it easier to understand the requirements and make sure the answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
{k: [d[i] for d in data] for i, k in enumerate(keys)}
```

Example:

```
>>> data=[[1422029700000, 230.84, 230.42, 230.31, 230.32, 378], [1422029800000, 231.84, 231.42, 231.31, 231.32, 379]]
>>> keys = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> {k: [d[i] for d in data] for i, k in enumerate(keys)}
{'c': [230.42, 231.42], 'a': [1422029700000, 1422029800000], 'b': [230.84, 231.84]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has everything in a list so if you want a list of dicts:

```
l1= [[1422029700000, 230.84, 230.42, 230.31, 230.32, 378], [1422029800000, 231.84, 231.42, 231.31, 231.32, 379]]
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e',"f"] # added f to match length of sublists
print([{a:list(b)} for a,b  in  zip(l2,zip(*l1))])
[{'a': [1422029700000, 1422029800000]}, {'b': [230.84, 231.84]}, {'c': [230.42, 231.42]}, {'d': [230.31, 231.31]}, {'e': [230.32, 231.32]}, {'f': [378, 379]}]
```

If you actually want a dict use a dict comprehension with zip:

```
print({a:list(b) for a,b  in  zip(l2,zip(*l1))})
{'f': [378, 379], 'e': [230.32, 231.32], 'a': [1422029700000, 1422029800000], 'b': [230.84, 231.84], 'c': [230.42, 231.42], 'd': [230.31, 231.31]}
```

You example also has a list of keys shorter than the length of your sublists so zipping will actually mean you *lose* values from your sublists so you may want to address that.

If you are using python2 you can use `itertools.izip`:

```
from itertools import izip
print({a:list(b) for a,b  in  izip(l2,zip(*l1))
```

Comment: Multiple dicts? It's really not matching with OP's desired output

Comment: @howaboutNO, the OP is using list syntax have you seen `['a': [1422029700000, 1422029800000]]` syntax with a dict before? The OP has everything in a list

Comment: You are right, I did have everything in a list. My mistake for not realizing I had the wrong syntax for a dict. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: @SeanU, no worries, make sure the length of your keys and length of your sublists match or you will lose data.

Comment: Yes, but if I want to lose the last piece of data in the list, I can make the length of keys 1 short right?

Comment: @SeanU, yes only  if you wanted to lose the last, zip will be exhausted on the shortest iterable, are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: Using Python3.4 never mind though, I found out all the data is important :)

Comment: then be careful with zip ;)